# How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use `matplotlib` to read in an RGB image and convert it to grayscale.

In matlab I use this:

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('image.png'));
```

In the [matplotlib tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/image_tutorial.html) they don't cover it. They just read in the image

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
```

and then they slice the array, but that's not the same thing as converting RGB to grayscale from what I understand.

```
lum_img = img[:,:,0]
```

I find it hard to believe that numpy or matplotlib doesn't have a built-in function to convert from rgb to gray. Isn't this a common operation in image processing?

I wrote a very simple function that works with the image imported using `imread` in 5 minutes. It's horribly inefficient, but that's why I was hoping for a professional implementation built-in.

Sebastian has improved my function, but I'm still hoping to find the built-in one.

matlab's (NTSC/PAL) implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def rgb2gray(rgb):

    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b

    return gray
```

Comment: Note that you can write the same thing as your rgb2gray function simply as: `gray = np.mean(rgb, -1)`. Maybe `rgb[...,:3]` there if it is actually rgba.

Comment: hmm, `gray = np.mean(rgb, -1)` works fine. thanks. Is there any reason not to use this? Why would I use the solutions in the answers below instead?

Comment: The [grayscale wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) says the method of converting RGB to grayscale is not unique, but gives a commonly used formulas based on luminance. It is quite different than `np.mean(rgb, -1)`.

Comment: so I guess I want [Matlab's version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2gray.html)? `0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B ` I'm assuming that it's the standard way of doing it.

Comment: Shouldn't be 0.2990 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B instead? The weight sum should equal to 1 and not 0.9999. Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Comment: You can find a detailed discussion on different methods of converting an image to grayscale here - https://e2eml.school/convert_rgb_to_grayscale.html

Answer (score 471, accepted):

How about doing it with [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

---

If an alpha (transparency) channel is present in the input image and should be preserved, use mode `LA`:

```
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
```

---

Using matplotlib and [the formula](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)

```
Y' = 0.2989 R + 0.5870 G + 0.1140 B
```

you could do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

img = mpimg.imread('image.png')     
gray = rgb2gray(img)    
plt.imshow(gray, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If he has to use `matplotlib` for some other reason, he should be able to use the builtin `colorsys.rgb_to_yiq()` to transform plus a slice to get just the luma channel.

Comment: why `.convert('LA')`? why not `.convert('gray')`? Seems needlessly cryptic. The [PIL documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) doesn't mention anything about 'LA' for the convert function.

Comment: Any reason why you chose to use rollaxis instead of an array slice? Is it supposed to be faster? Slices seem to be more readable. I'm still surprised that rgb2gray hasn't been implemented in the library yet. I guess this is the best I can hope for, for now. Thanks.

Comment: Although array slices like `r = rgb[...,0]` might be more readable (and the code may even be a bit faster), writing it out for `r`, `g` and `b` is a bit repetitive, and would not generalize well to more variables. I think either way has its advantages.

Comment: using PIL: `cannot write mode LA as JPEG`, I needed to use L mode not LA

Comment: To get the exact same results as with [Matlab's version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python/12201744#comment16351468_12201577) (which differs marginally from the [ITU-R 601-2 luma transform](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert), I specified an adjusted matix: `img.convert('L', (0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140, 0))`.

Comment: This `img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')` needs to be `img = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')`

Comment: What is LA?  Specifically what is L with alpha?

Comment: @BluePython: `LA` mode has luminosity (brightness) and alpha. If you use `LA` mode, then `greyscale.png` will be an RGBA image with the alpha channel of `image.png` preserved. If you use `L` mode, then `greyscale.png` will be an RGB image (with no alpha).

Comment: In case it matters for anyone's use-case, note that `LA` is an 8-bit mode and so `.convert('LA')` will reduce your color depth to 8-bit if it was originally higher.

Comment: Updated link for @waspinator's comments: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: I have seen this RGB arrangement (0.299R, 0.587B, 0.114G) in a couple of documentations, yet whatever RGB values I use in `np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])`, .e.g. 0.9, 0.9, 0.9 ... even 0.0, 0.1., 0.0 (There must be at least a non zero value) the result is always the same!  Not for you? Any idea why?

Comment: @Apostolos: Thanks for pointing out this bug. The results are different, but depending on your image, not as different as they should be. `imshow` ["normalizes"](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib-colors-normalize) scalar data by default. Thus multiplying by `[0.0, 0.1, 0.0]` was equivalent to multiplying by `[0, 1, 0]` after normalization. To prevent `imshow` from doing this rescaling, use `vmin=0, vmax=1`. I've made this change above too.

Comment: @unutbu, this is a great solution. Now we can talk! Note however, that -- with me at least -- it works only with `matplotlib.image` and with PNG files. It doesn't work with `imageio` and JPEG files. But who cares? :)

Answer (score 98):

You can also use [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#rgb2gray), which provides some functions to convert an image in `ndarray`, like `rgb2gray`.

```
from skimage import color
from skimage import io

img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('image.png'))
```

**Notes**: The weights used in this conversion are calibrated for contemporary CRT phosphors:  Y = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B

Alternatively, you can read image in grayscale by:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('image.png', as_gray=True)
```

Comment: is it normal that I'm getting 0<values<1 ? Am I supposed to multiply them by 255 to get the real gray scale?

Comment: knowing that my aim is to use GLCM features (greycoprops)

Comment: Note for io.imread: "as_grey" has been deprecated in favor of "as_gray". Same usage, just Americanized spelling. :)

Comment: I believe this is the most useful answer to question at hand, output of this is also compatible with matplotlib and numpy.

Comment: I am using the color object but my image is sort of reddish now and not gray (black and white). I need to use `cmap` as `gray' then only the image is shown as gray in `pyplot.imshow()` ? Any thoughts ? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 94):

Three of the suggested methods were tested for speed with 1000 RGBA PNG images (224 x 256 pixels) running with Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xeon E5 2670 with SSD).

**Average run times**

`pil  :` 1.037 seconds

`scipy:` 1.040 seconds

`sk   :` 2.120 seconds

PIL and SciPy gave identical `numpy` arrays (ranging from 0 to 255). SkImage gives arrays from 0 to 1. In addition the colors are converted slightly different, see the example from the [CUB-200 dataset.](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/visipedia/CUB-200.html)

`SkImage:`  [image: SkImage]

`PIL    :`  [image: PIL]

`SciPy  :`  [image: SciPy]

`Original:` [image: Original]

`Diff    :` [image]

**Code**

1. Performance

   ```
   run_times = dict(sk=list(), pil=list(), scipy=list())
   for t in range(100):
       start_time = time.time()
       for i in range(1000):
           z = random.choice(filenames_png)
           img = skimage.color.rgb2gray(skimage.io.imread(z))
       run_times['sk'].append(time.time() - start_time)
   ```

   ```
   start_time = time.time()
   for i in range(1000):
       z = random.choice(filenames_png)
       img = np.array(Image.open(z).convert('L'))
   run_times['pil'].append(time.time() - start_time)

   start_time = time.time()
   for i in range(1000):
       z = random.choice(filenames_png)
       img = scipy.ndimage.imread(z, mode='L')
   run_times['scipy'].append(time.time() - start_time)
   ```

   for k, v in run_times.items():
       print('{:5}: {:0.3f} seconds'.format(k, sum(v) / len(v)))
2. Output

   ```
   z = 'Cardinal_0007_3025810472.jpg'
   img1 = skimage.color.rgb2gray(skimage.io.imread(z)) * 255
   IPython.display.display(PIL.Image.fromarray(img1).convert('RGB'))
   img2 = np.array(Image.open(z).convert('L'))
   IPython.display.display(PIL.Image.fromarray(img2))
   img3 = scipy.ndimage.imread(z, mode='L')
   IPython.display.display(PIL.Image.fromarray(img3))
   ```
3. Comparison

   ```
   img_diff = np.ndarray(shape=img1.shape, dtype='float32')
   img_diff.fill(128)
   img_diff += (img1 - img3)
   img_diff -= img_diff.min()
   img_diff *= (255/img_diff.max())
   IPython.display.display(PIL.Image.fromarray(img_diff).convert('RGB'))
   ```
4. Imports

   ```
   import skimage.color
   import skimage.io
   import random
   import time
   from PIL import Image
   import numpy as np
   import scipy.ndimage
   import IPython.display
   ```
5. Versions

   ```
   skimage.version
   0.13.0
   scipy.version
   0.19.1
   np.version
   1.13.1
   ```

Comment: SciPy's image I/O is *literally* PIL/Pillow. Hence, testing SciPy is effectively retesting PIL/Pillow with negligible overhead introduced by SciPy's wrapper functions. It would have been *much* more useful to substitute OpenCV (which does *not* leverage PIL/Pillow) for SciPy (which does). Nonetheless, thanks for the dedicated benchmarking! The discernable slowdown imposed by SciKit is fascinating... **and horrifying.**

Answer (score 42):

You can always read the image file as grayscale right from the beginning using [`imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) from OpenCV:

```
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg', 0)
```

Furthermore, in case you want to read the image as RGB, do some processing and then convert to Gray Scale you could use [`cvtcolor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) from OpenCV:

```
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: Ftr: The `0` flag is [`cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.imread).

Answer (score 29):

The fastest and current way is to use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/), installed via `pip install Pillow`.

The code is then:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('input_file.jpg').convert('L')
img.save('output_file.jpg')
```

Comment: note that, if you're not chaining your methods like in the example above, `convert` returns a converted copy of the image

Comment: does not work for 32 bit PNG, values will be _clamped_ to 255

Answer (score 12):

The tutorial is cheating because it is starting with a greyscale image encoded in RGB, so they are just slicing a single color channel and treating it as greyscale.  The basic steps you need to do are to transform from the RGB colorspace to a colorspace that encodes with something approximating the luma/chroma model, such as YUV/YIQ or HSL/HSV, then slice off the luma-like channel and use that as your greyscale image.  `matplotlib` does not appear to provide a mechanism to convert to YUV/YIQ, but it does let you convert to HSV.

Try using `matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(img)` then slicing the last value (V) from the array for your grayscale.  It's not quite the same as a luma value, but it means you can do it all in `matplotlib`.

Background:

- http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Alternatively, you could use PIL or the builtin `colorsys.rgb_to_yiq()` to convert to a colorspace with a true luma value.  You could also go all in and roll your own luma-only converter, though that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 12):

Using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale)

```
Y' = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B
```

We can do

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pic = imageio.imread('(image)')
gray = lambda rgb : np.dot(rgb[... , :3] , [0.299 , 0.587, 0.114]) 
gray = gray(pic)  
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap(name = 'gray'))
```

However, the [GIMP](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-tool-desaturate.html) converting color to grayscale image software has three algorithms to do the task.

Answer (score 9):

you could do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def rgb_to_gray(img):
        grayImage = np.zeros(img.shape)
        R = np.array(img[:, :, 0])
        G = np.array(img[:, :, 1])
        B = np.array(img[:, :, 2])

        R = (R *.299)
        G = (G *.587)
        B = (B *.114)

        Avg = (R+G+B)
        grayImage = img.copy()

        for i in range(3):
           grayImage[:,:,i] = Avg
           
        return grayImage       

image = mpimg.imread("your_image.png")   
grayImage = rgb_to_gray(image)  
plt.imshow(grayImage)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using NumPy/SciPy already you may [as well use](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html):

`scipy.ndimage.imread(file_name, mode='L')`

Comment: Both `scipy.ndimage.imread()` and `scipy.misc.imread()` are [**formally deprecated**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) in SciPy 1.0.0 and will be **permanently removed** in SciPy 1.2.0. While SciPy's documentation recommends [`imageio.imread()`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html?highlight=imread#imageio.imread) as a suitable replacement, this function's API is bare bones to the point of absurdity. It provides *no* support for grayscale conversion and thus remains unsuitable for many applications – including ours. `</sigh>`

Answer (score 6):

With OpenCV its simple:

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("flower.jpg")

# To Grayscale
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite("grayscale.jpg", im)

# To Black & White
im = cv2.threshold(im, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite("black-white.jpg", im)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use img.Convert(), supports “L”, “RGB” and “CMYK.” mode

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("IMG/center_2018_02_03_00_34_32_784.jpg")
img.convert('L')

print np.array(img)
```

Output:

```
[[135 123 134 ...,  30   3  14]
 [137 130 137 ...,   9  20  13]
 [170 177 183 ...,  14  10 250]
 ..., 
 [112  99  91 ...,  90  88  80]
 [ 95 103 111 ..., 102  85 103]
 [112  96  86 ..., 182 148 114]]
```

Comment: should the 5th line be `img = img.convert('L')` ?

Answer (score 3):

I came to this question via Google, searching for a way to convert an already loaded image to grayscale.

Here is a way to do it with SciPy:

```
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage

# Load an example image
# Use scipy.ndimage.imread(file_name, mode='L') if you have your own
img = scipy.misc.face()

# Convert the image
R = img[:, :, 0]
G = img[:, :, 1]
B = img[:, :, 2]
img_gray = R * 299. / 1000 + G * 587. / 1000 + B * 114. / 1000

# Show the image
scipy.misc.imshow(img_gray)
```

Comment: Nice. I just want to note the a shorter solution would be `img_gray = numpy.average(img, weights=[0.299, 0.587, 0.114], axis=2)`

Comment: Both `scipy.ndimage.imread()` and `scipy.misc.imread()` are [**formally deprecated**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) in SciPy 1.0.0 and will be **permanently removed** in SciPy 1.2.0. You probably just want to use Pillow's builtin grayscale conversion support (ala [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/2809027)), instead.

Comment: What are the magic numbers in your code? 299, 587, 114...

Answer (score 2):

**When the values in a pixel across all 3 color channels (RGB) are same then that pixel will always be in grayscale format.**

One of a simple & intuitive method to convert a RGB image to Grayscale is by taking the mean of all color channels in each pixel and assigning the value back to that pixel.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img=np.array(Image.open('sample.jpg')) #Input - Color image
gray_img=img.copy()

for clr in range(img.shape[2]):
    gray_img[:,:,clr]=img.mean(axis=2) #Take mean of all 3 color channels of each pixel and assign it back to that pixel(in copied image)

#plt.imshow(gray_img) #Result - Grayscale image
```

Input Image:
[image: Input Image]

Output Image:
[image: Output Image]

Comment: You can use this: img = np.mean(color_img, axis=2)
But it is not correct way to do it, read this: https://e2eml.school/convert_rgb_to_grayscale.html

Comment: gray_img still got 3 channels. why it so??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my image is 3 channel in its original form

```
my_image = cv2.imread("./5d10e5939c5101174c54bb98.png")
#greyscaling the image
image_sum = my_image.sum(axis=2)
new_image = image_sum/image_sum.max()
```

`new_image` is my single channel greyscale image

```
plt.figure(figsize=[12,8])
plt.imshow(new_image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[ **This is without using cv2's `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` parameter or PIL's `.convert('L')` method** ]

Answer (score -3):

```
image=myCamera.getImage().crop(xx,xx,xx,xx).scale(xx,xx).greyscale()
```

You can use `greyscale()` directly for the transformation.