# Convert image data to grayscale from npy file in pylearn2

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pylearn

I'm training a simple convolution neural network using pylearn2. I have my RGB image data stored in a npy file. Is there anyway to convert that data directly to grayscale data directly from the npy file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a standalone file then load the file using [numpy.load](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy-load) then convert the content using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/convert-rgb-image-to-grayscale-in-python):

```py
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.144])
```

If the file is part of a pylearn2 dataset (resulted from `use_design_loc()`), then load the dataset

```py
from pylearn2.utils import serial
serial.load("file.pkl")
```

and apply `rgb2gray()` function to `X` member (I assume a `DenseDesignMatrix`).