# What's the best way to greyscale in python/django?

Tags: python, django, image, imagemagick, opencv3.0

I want to greyscale my images that will be uploaded into django. So I found two ways, either opencv or imagemagick. And within imagemagick, imagemagickWand might be better because it's reduced.

From the tutorials I think openCV is easier to implement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually want the images to be converted to grayscale, or just *displayed* that way (which you can do with CSS)?

Comment: no I want them converted, cnavas would be another option but I want to do it in python thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with django. [Here's a relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/168775) that discusses converting an image to grayscale.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)

Comment: No, I'm looking for advantages and disadvantages with the different methods, PIL is another one thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best way to greyscale in python/django?

Take your pick.

ImageMagick's wand library

```py
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename='logo:') as img:
    img.colorspace = 'gray'
    img.save(filename='logo_gray.jpg')
```

Or CV2

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('example_gray.jpg',gray)
```

Both projects are mature, stable, and have a large community base. Try installing both libraries, and experimenting.

In the end grayscale is just (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)).

```py
Y = 0.2126 * RED + 0.7152 * GREEN + 0.0722 * BLUE
```

Both do this well, and depend on delegates (i.e. libjpeg) to read & write image formats.

Comment: @klausruprecht I think the bulk of PIL folks have moved to pillow. But if I give an example, it would be the same 4 lines as above. Import, read, gray, write.

Comment: Are you sure it is img.colorspace = 'gray'; and not img.type = 'grayscale'; ?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner Both work, but with different internal dynamics. OP did not specify context of grayscale.

Comment: Ok, thanks! how can you manually adjust the grayscaling? Everytime when I use wand it turns pngs with transparent background into black background?

Answer (score 7):

You can get nicer results if you convert to linear light first.

An sRGB image will have a gamma of about 2.4 applied to it, that is, there is more range in the bright areas than the dark. If you do `0.2 r + 0.7 g + 0.1 b` directly on an sRGB image it can distort lightness relationships, for example:

[image]

From the left, those are the original image, a greyscale made by a simple recombination of sRGB, a greyscale made by a very fancy local adaptive algorithm, and a greyscale made in linear light. The linear light version keeps the red-blue difference better than the non-linear, though it doesn't look quite as nice as the adaptive version. You can [read about the adaptive algorithm here](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ApparentGreyscale/).

Conversion to linear light can be done by a simple ungamma, if you are sure you have sRGB, or, better, by converting to XYZ using an ICC profile. [pyvips](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvips) has a linear-light greyscale conversion built in, try:

```
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("/home/john/pics/k2.jpg", access="sequential") 
image = image.colourspace("b-w")
image.write_to_file("x.jpg")
```

The advantages for vips over PIL or imagemagick would be better quality, [faster, and much lower memory use](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use). For a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel RGB JPEG, I see:

```
$ time ./magickwand.py 
real    0m2.613s
user    0m2.084s
sys 0m0.500s
peak RES 840MB
$ time ./vips.py
real    0m1.722s
user    0m5.716s
sys 0m0.116s
peak RES 54MB
```

That's on a two-core laptop.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is awesome! Exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: That seems like a cool library I can't import it though. I used `sudo apt-get install libvips` but I still get an error cannot import Vips

Comment: What version of vips is this? The current Python binding appears in v7.42 and later. Before then there was a simpler Python interface based on SWIG which you imported with `from vipsCC import *`.

Comment: I updated the sample code for the new libvips Python binding. You can install with just `pip install pyvips` now, and it should work on Windows, macOS and Linux.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Adaptive Greyscale, might there be an open source Python implementation?