# animating image stack with vispy

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, vispy, glumpy

I'm trying to migrate from MATLAB to Python and one of the things I frequently rely on during development in Matlab is the ability to rapidly visualize slices of a datacube by looping through layers and calling drawnow, e.g.

```
tst = randn(1000,1000,100);
for n = 1:size(tst, 3)
    imagesc(tst(:,:,n));
    drawnow;
end
```

When I tic/toc this in MATLAB it shows that the figure is updating at about 28fps. In contrast, when I try to do this using matplotlib's imshow() command this runs at a snails pace in comparison, even using set_data().

```
    import matplotlib as mp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    tmp = np.random.random((1000,1000,100))

    myfig = plt.imshow(tmp[:,:,i], aspect='auto')
    for i in np.arange(0,tmp.shape[2]):

        myfig.set_data(tmp[:,:,i])
        mp.pyplot.title(str(i))
        mp.pyplot.pause(0.001)
```

On my computer this runs at about 16fps with the default (very small) scale, and if I resize it to be larger and the same size as the matlab figure it slows down to about 5 fps. From some older threads I saw a suggestion to use glumpy and I installed this along with all of the appropriate packages and libraries (glfw, etc.), and the package itself works fine but it no longer supports the easy image visualization that was [suggested in a previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003094/how-can-i-speed-up-an-animation).

I then downloaded vispy, and I can make an image with it using code from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826807/display-image-in-grayscale-using-vispy) as a template:

```
    import sys
    from vispy import scene
    from vispy import app
    import numpy as np

    canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive')
    canvas.size = 800, 600
    canvas.show()

    # Set up a viewbox to display the image with interactive pan/zoom
    view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()

    # Create the image
    img_data = np.random.random((800,800, 3))
    image = scene.visuals.Image(img_data, parent=view.scene)
    view.camera.set_range()

    # unsuccessfully tacked on the end to see if I can modify the figure.
    # Does nothing.
    img_data_new = np.zeros((800,800, 3))
    image = scene.visuals.Image(img_data_new, parent=view.scene)
    view.camera.set_range()
```

Vispy seems very fast and this looks like it will get me there, but how do you update the canvas with new data? Thank you,

Comment: [Fast Live Plotting in Matplotlib / PyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126176/fast-live-plotting-in-matplotlib-pyplot) shows a solution to make this faster in matplotlib and also an alternative with other python libraries (PyQtGraph).

Comment: I'll look into PyQtGraph, it might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

See [ImageVisual.set_data](http://vispy.org/visuals.html?highlight=imagevisual#vispy.visuals.ImageVisual.set_data) method

```
# Create the image
img_data = np.random.random((800,800, 3))
image = scene.visuals.Image(img_data, parent=view.scene)
view.camera.set_range()

# Generate new data :
img_data_new = np.zeros((800,800, 3))
img_data_new[400:, 400:, 0] = 1.  # red square
image.set_data(img_data_new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't work for me, the figure doesn't change & no errors are thrown.

Comment: Never mind - it works! Thank you! I had accidentally duplicated a line of code when testing it previously which is why it didn't work. It doesn't, however, update continuously if I put it in a loop to try to animate something.