# Use Numpy to convert rgb pixel array into grayscale

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

What's the best way to use Numpy to convert a size (x, y, 3) array of rgb pixel values to a size (x, y, 1) array of grayscale pixel values?

I have a function, rgbToGrey(rgbArray) that can take the [r,g,b] array and return the greyscale value. I'd like to use it along with Numpy to shrink the 3rd dimension of my array from size 3 to size 1.

How can I do this?

Note: This would be pretty easy if I had the original image and could grayscale it first using Pillow, but I don't have it.

UPDATE:

The function I was looking for was `np.dot()`.

**From the answer to this quesiton**:

Assuming we convert rgb into greyscale through the formula:

.3r * .6g * .1b = grey,

we can do `np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [.3, .6, .1])` to get what I'm looking for, a 2d array of grey-only values.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See the answers in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python).

Essentially:

```
gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the np.dot() method I was needing!

Comment: could you please tell how to convert rgb array to black an white image? or should I ask new question?

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh You can use the fromarray function of the PIL Image. Convert the rgb array to gray scale using the method mentioned here, then im = Image.fromarray(grey_array).  If you pass the rgb array, then you can get a color image Image.fromarray(rgb_array, mode='RGB')

Comment: alternatively: `rgb[..., :3] @ [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]` see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html