# How do I change the last array dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a numpy array that the shape is as follow:

```
(98, 15, 64, 64, 3)
```

I want to change it to

```
(98, 15, 64, 64, 1)
```

How can I do that? 
The last dimension is the image channel such that 3 is the rgb and 1 is the grayscale. I want to represents the color cods as grayscale because the image is just black and white color.

Comment: `data[...,[0]].shape` maybe this?

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample code?

Comment: how gonna that be possible?? 98*15*64*64*3 will never equals 98*15*64*64*1

Comment: You need to look around before asking: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971663/use-numpy-to-convert-rgb-pixel-array-into-grayscale?rq=1)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)  [3](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)

Comment: numpy.rollaxis?

Comment: looking for `np.dot()`?