# Python ndimage: Converting an existing ndarray into greyscale

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, ndimage

During my python 2.7 exploration trying to use `scipy` I have made the following simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
# -*- Mode: python; c-basic-offset: 4 -*-

from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import argparse
import Image

def getArguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="An simple Image processor")
    parser.add_argument('image_file', metavar="FILENAME", type=str,
                        help="The image file that will be read In order to be processed")
    return parser.parse_args()


def getImagePathFromArguments():
    '''
    :return: string
    '''
    args = getArguments()
    return args.image_file


def loadImage(image):
    '''
    :param image: The path of the Image
    :return: 
    '''
    return misc.imread(image)


def grayscale(imgData):
    #Greyscale action done here
    pass


def blur(imgData):
    '''
    :param nparray imgData: 
    :return: 
    '''
    return ndimage.gaussian_filter(imgData, 1)

def saveImage(path, imgData):
    im = Image.fromarray(imgData)
    im.save(path)


def main():
    imagePath = getImagePathFromArguments()
    print "Loading Image from %s" % (imagePath,)
    image = loadImage(imagePath)

    while True:

        print "Select \n"
        print "1. Greyscale"
        print "2. Bluring"
        option = int(raw_input("Please do your option: "))

        if (option != 1 and option != 2):
            print "Wrong Option"
        else:
            processedData=0
            if option == 1:
                processedData = grayscale(image)
            elif option == 2:
                print "Bluring Image"
                processedData = blur(image)

            saveImagePath = raw_input("Where to you want to store the image?")
            saveImage(saveImagePath, processedData)
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That does simple process on images such as bluring and greayscale. I managed to do the blur from an already loaded image but how about greyscale?

The closest I found is [How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python#12201744) But they do not provide a solution using the ndimage.

Also ndimage can convert during opening and not using an already opened image.

I also tried to implement the method `greyscale` with as seen in http://ebanshi.cc/questions/108516/convert-rgb-image-to-grayscale-in-python:

```
def grayscale(imgData):
    r=imgData[:,:,0]
    g=imgData[:,:,1]
    b=imgData[:,:,2]
    return  r * 299. / 1000 + g * 587. / 1000 + b * 114. / 1000
```

But I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/python/Basic/scripy/scipy_image_examples.py", line 83, in 
>       main()
>     File "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/python/Basic/scripy/scipy_image_examples.py", line 78, in main
>       saveImage(saveImagePath, processedData)
>     File "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/python/Basic/scripy/scipy_image_examples.py", line 52, in saveImage
>       im.save(path)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1675, in save
>       save_handler(self, fp, filename)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 682, in _save
>       raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as PNG" % mode)
>   IOError: cannot write mode F as PNG

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I needed to create my own function. It was not that hard:

```
def grayscale(imgData):
    r=imgData[:,:,0]
    g=imgData[:,:,1]
    b=imgData[:,:,2]
    return  r/3 + g /3 + b/3
```

Comment: You solution still does not work. Please see my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Dimitris you solution does not work because you are trying to save a file with an invalid mode. F is for 32 bit floating point pixels and when you call `saveImage` the image data are still in F mode. You can check by yourself by adding the line: `print im.mode` in the `saveImage` function.

See http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes for all modes on the PIL library

To fix that you just need to convert the image data to RGB mode again by calling `convert('RGB')` before saving.

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert