# Python3 reduce array from (x,y,3) to (x,y,1) (rgb to greyscale)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am quite new to python, therefore I might risk a duplicate (but I don't know how to ask the web yet).

I have coded the following method. It converts an array(ROWS,COLS,3) to array(ROWS,COLS,1)

```
def convert_greyscale( rgb ):
    rgb_greyscale = np.zeros( (rgb.shape[0],rgb.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
    for row in range(0, rgb.shape[0]:
        for col in range(0, rgb.shape[1]):
            rgb_greyscale[row][col] = int(0.2126 * rgb[row][col][0] + 0.7152 * rgb[row][col][1] + 0.0722 * rgb[row][col][2])
    return rgb_greyscale
```

Sadly I wasn't able to reproduce it shorter. There is already a post where someone already mentioned a solution with **np.dot**, however it is not the same result as my small function.

How can I rewrite this code using more efficient (lambda) or at least more elegant expressions?

And is this method efficient?

Comment: Just use proper weights there : `[0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]` with the answers to the linked question, specifically this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/

Comment: yeah I've found this Solution too, (mentioning np.dot). It doesn't deliver the same results.

Comment: It does. You also need to convert to `int` dtype as you were doing in your code and seems like you are skipping the last row and col, so pad with zeros.

Comment: the -1 was incorrect. forgot to delete it. 
so basicly what differs from this answer is: 
np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]).astype(np.uint8) ?

Comment: Not sure which `-1` you are referring to. This is as simple as : `np.dot(rgb, [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]).astype('uint8')`.

Comment: can I expect any performance differences when using
`np.dot(img, [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]).astype('uint8')`
over
`(0.2126*rgb[:,:,0]+0.7152*rgb[:,:,1]+0.0722*rgb[:,:,2]).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Well there's a faster way : `np.tensordot(rgb, [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722], axes=((-1,-1)))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150000/discussion-between-coco-and-divakar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
return (0.2126*rgb[:,:,0]+0.7152*rgb[:,:,1]+0.0722*rgb[:,:,2])\
           .astype(np.uint8)
```

No need for loops here, let numpy do the iterations.

Comment: Oh thanks! that looks easy and elegant.