# 3d numpy array to grayscale picture

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, grayscale

while extracting the cifar10 dataset im confronted by arrays with the dimension of 32x32x3.

i can plot the image in colour with e.g. plt.imshow(train_data[2]); whats a common way to transform the array to the dimension 32x32 with grayscale values?

```
train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels = 
load_cifar10_data(data_dir)

print(train_data.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)
```

output:

(50000, 32, 32, 3)
(50000,)

meanwhile, i'm just saving the images and read them again, but i guess there is a by far more elegant way to directly store the pictures to grayscale.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You can use your current 3D array to plot a grayscale image using matplotlib's [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) as described [here](http://www.imagexd.org/tutorial/lessons/0_images_are_arrays.html#displaying-images-using-matplotlib).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(train_data , cmap = "gray")
```

Comment: i tried already, various cmap/interpolation settings, it simply plots it in color; i really dont know why: plt.imshow(train_data[2], cmap="gray")
plt.show()

Comment: This does not change the values of the array.