# Conversion from RGB to grey scale 64 bit - calculation used?

Tags: python, scikit-image

When I look at imread function in skimage.io, it doesn't say what calculation is used when as_grey=True is set, is there a way to find the calculation going on behind the scenes?

Link to lib:
*(http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)*

Text from link above:
*as_grey : bool
If True, convert color images to grey-scale (64-bit floats). Images that are already in grey-scale format are not converted.*

Example:
RGB - [108 123 128]

When I use convert('L'), it gets converted to 119 and that's inline with the formula on this post [How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)
But when I use imread(img, as_grey = True), it gives me a value of 0.47126667, which is lower than the value if I were to divide the 119 value with the max value of pixel in that image to convert the values to 0-1 scale.

If you want to view the results, here's sample code:

```html
from __future__ import division
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np

image_open = Image.open(image).convert('L')
np_image_open = np.array(image_open)
print (np_image_open[:10,0])

print (np_image_open[:10,0]/np.max(np_image_open))

image_open = imread(image, as_grey = True)
print (image_open[:10,0])

image_open = imread(image)
print (image_open[:10,0])
```

Comment: I think it just calls `skimage.color.rgb2gray` on the image.  Conventions for floating point image representation can be found in the user guide.

Comment: thanks @StefanvanderWalt. Went through the document, pretty dense so didn't understand a lot of things but still a good read.