# Python2 OpenCV3.3-dev: imread with grayscale is coming out all wonky

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Using python2 with opencv 3.3-dev

if i try to do a simple:

```
gray = imread('img.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

and try to show the image with

```
plt.imshow(img), plt.show()
```

(where plt is matplotlib.pyplot)

the resulting image is not at all gray, and really green and not at all the original colors, or grayscale...

heres what it looks like: 
[image]

Does anybody know whats wrong?

Comment: Use `plt.show(img, cmap="gray")`?

Comment: as a reference can you post the original picture?

Comment: plt might recognize the pixels as (gray value, 0, 0), if the first value represents green the picture will be different shades of green

Comment: here it is: https://i.imgur.com/iITRlSZ.jpg

using cmap="gray" seemed to have solved it, but is this just how the image is displayed? is the image actually in grayscale?

Comment: @elliot430 if you dont specify for plt to show a grayscale image it will pad other colors with 0s

Comment: @DavidG well im using opencv for a project that im just starting on, never touched this before so.... you might see me around a lot asking for help in the near future haha

Comment: @Eumel I see, so from my understanding, this is just a problem with the actual "display" part, the image was actually already in grayscale?

Comment: If you didn't want to use openCV, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python) will be helpful