# Python: Perform Grey Image to RGB

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, opencv3.1, rgbcolor

I have a grey image and I want to convert it into RGB. How will I do it in OpenCV?

```
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('Grey Scale Image', image)
cv2.waitKey()


backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.imshow('GRAY2RGB Image', backtorgb)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I tried GRAY2RGB, but it doesn't change the image. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here. You can't remove all the colour information and then magically re-create it from nowhere.

Once you delete it, it's gone.

So what is `GRAY2RGB` for? It just takes the grey channel and replicates it into the R, G and B channels, so you have a 3-channel image, but all 3 are the same, hence it looks grey.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

There are other ways to do it, you don't need openCV, in the end the image is a matrix an you can do it with multiplication, look at this post:
[How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)

EDIT: Giving the solution in case link changes.

An image can be seen as 3 matrices, one for red, one for green and one for blue, the three channel colours RGB, each one with the information for each pixel ranging between 0 and 255. To transform it to gray scale image it is necessary to sum all the colours by the representation of their luminosity, which is a coeficient already known obtained in an ecuation system:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
    return gray
```

In openCV I don't know if there is a function, however this should be enough.

Comment: But this do the contrary of the question (you wrote about rgb to gray), it was requested gray to rgb.