# How to convert a RGB image (3 channel) to grayscale (1 channel) and save it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, rgb, grayscale

Working with a deep learning project and I have a lot of images, that don't need to have colors. I saved them doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imsave('image.png', image, format='png', cmap='gray')
```

However later when I checked the shape of the image the result is:

```
import cv2
img_rgb = cv2.imread('image.png')
print(img_rgb.shape)
(196,256,3)
```

So even though the image I view is in grayscale, I still have 3 color channels. I realized I had to do some algebric operations in order to convert those 3 channels into 1 single channel.

I have tried the methods described on the thread "[How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)" but I'm confused.

For example, when to do the conversion using:

```
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
img_gray = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('image.png'))
plt.imsave('image_gray.png', img_gray, format='png')
```

However when I load the new image and check its shape:

```
img_gr = cv2.imread('image_gray.png')
print(img_gr.shape)
(196,256,3)
```

I tried the other methods on that thread but the results are the same. My goal is to have images with a (196,256,1) shape, given how much less computationally intensive it will be for a Convolutional Neural Network.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution to it? I used matplotlib and a manual method but both result in 3 channel grayscale image :|

Answer (score 5):

Your first code block:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imsave('image.png', image, format='png', cmap='gray')
```

This is saving the image as RGB, because `cmap='gray'` is ignored when supplying RGB data to imsave (see [pyplot docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html)).

You can convert your data into grayscale by taking the average of the three bands, either using `color.rgb2gray` as you have, or I tend to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

img_rgb = np.random.rand(196,256,3)
print('RGB image shape:', img_rgb.shape)

img_gray = np.mean(img_rgb, axis=2)
print('Grayscale image shape:', img_gray.shape)
```

Output:

```
RGB image shape: (196, 256, 3)
Grayscale image shape: (196, 256)
```

`img_gray` is now the correct shape, however if you save it using `plt.imsave`, it will still write three bands, with R == G == B for each pixel. This is because, I believe, a PNG file requires three (or four) bands. Warning: I am not sure about this: I expect to be corrected.

```
plt.imsave('image_gray.png', img_gray, format='png')
new_img = cv2.imread('image_gray.png')
print('Loaded image shape:', new_img.shape)
```

Output:

```
Loaded image shape: (196, 256, 3)
```

One way to avoid this is to save the images as numpy files, or indeed to save a batch of images as numpy files:

```
np.save('np_image.npy', img_gray)
new_np = np.load('np_image.npy')
print('new_np shape:', new_np.shape)
```

Output:

```
new_np shape: (196, 256)
```

The other thing you could do is save the grayscale png (using `imsave`) but then only read in the first band:

```
finalimg = cv2.imread('image_gray.png',0)
print('finalimg image shape:', finalimg.shape)
```

Output:

```
finalimg image shape: (196, 256)
```

Comment: PNG does not require three bands. RBGA is very common, and grayscale or grayscale with alpha is also possible.

Comment: @HåkenLid I'd appreciate an example of how to save just one band to a PNG.

Comment: The official PNG spec supports it. https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/ "Indexed-color, grayscale, and truecolor images are supported, plus an optional alpha channel. Sample depths range from 1 to 16 bits.". But it's entirely possible that there are graphics libraries that don't fully support all parts of the PNG standard.

Comment: Thank you this is very useful! I think a good course of action to take would then be: 
1 - to load the images as they are (3 color channel)
2 - load the data and convert it to 1 color channel
3 - save it as numpy file
4 - feed that into the neural network

The only problem I can anticipate with this is that I think the expected input will be (196,256,1) and the one I will have is a (196,256). Are these equivalent?

Comment: You can use numpy.expand_dims(array, 2) on your input to add the extra expected dimension.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, Keras, the deep-learning library I'm using has its own method of converting images to a single color channel (grayscale) in its image pre-processing step.

When using the `ImageDataGenerator` class the `flow_from_directory` method takes the `color_mode` argument. Setting `color_mode = "grayscale"` will automatically convert the PNG into a single color channel!

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-methods

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: The problem is I am not reading from disk! I am taking image from camera and I want to convert it immediately to grayscale without saving it on disk!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just add extra channels that have the same value as the graysacale , maybe to use a specific model that requires 3 channel input_shape .

lets say your pictures are **28 X 28** and so you have a shape of (28 , 28 , 1)
    def add_extra_channels_to_pic(pic):

```
if pic.shape == (28 , 28 , 1):
    pic = pic.reshape(28,28)
    pic =  np.array([pic , pic , pic])
    # to make the channel axis in the end
    pic = np.moveaxis(pic , 0 , -1) 
    return pic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
import imageio
new_data = imageio.imread("file_path", as_gray =True)
imageio.imsave("file_path", new_data)
```

The optional argument "as_gray = True" in line 2 of the code does the actual conversion.