# Converting .jpg to .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a .jpg image to .txt but when I run the code below I get the error "ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead". What am I doing wrong?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('Moon.jpg')
pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size 
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in range(height)]
np.savetxt("Moon_data.txt", pixels, fmt='%d', delimiter=" ")
```

Comment: [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) expects a 1D or 2D array-like object. Your providing a 3D array.

Comment: is it fine if you use a custom data format ?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your image into grayscale, which is a 1D array. This can be saved into a text file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/3883569) answer provides to ways of converting an image to grayscale. One using Pillow and the other doing the calculation on your own.