# How can I convert RGB image to single channel grey image, and save it using python?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

Question is simple.
I have lots of 3-channel RGB images.
(Their colors are already grey, but you know, RGB format.)
What I want is converting them to grey-scale image with 1-channel.

I tried opencv to do it.
But after I save it with png format, it ruined.
I think structure of png file is the reason...

Anyway, is there any nice way to do this?
Recommendation for 1-channel image format will also be really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you doing this to reduce the image size?

Comment: Umm.. there are several reasons, but main reason is following two.
1. My images are already grey, so as you mentioned I want to save my memory.
2. I will use these images for inputs of machine learning. I hope using 1-channel image as input can make my network to learn better and faster.

Comment: I found different ways of doing what you're asking here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python

Comment: @Sebastien I also found that and already tried. But result of conversion was not 1-channel grey image. It was just 3-channel RGB image with grey color. (Basically nothing changed in my case, because already all grey.)

Comment: Have you tried all the answers? Notably the one with `gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: Please show the code you tried and what didn't work. It would be very easy to suggest another format but that might bring new problems. You also need to say **why** you are trying to do this and also what package and whar processing you intend to use later on. Nobody wants to advise you incorrectly.

Comment: For your 2nd reason, you can convert images to gray before using for training.

Comment: PNG supports grayscale (1,2,4,8,16 bpp, and also with alpha transparency at 8 and 16bpp). OpenCV will write a grayscale PNG if passed a 1 channel image (verified). Problem is likely somewhere else (but impossible to tell due to lack of provided details).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a few dozen images, a quick way to convert them all to single-channel, greyscale images that OpenCV can read is with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal - it is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, to make a single channel 8-bit [PGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) version of all PNGs in the current directory:

```
magick mogrify -format PGM -colorspace gray -depth 8 *.png
```

If you have many hundreds or thousands of images, use **GNU Parallel** as well to get all your CPU cores running in parallel:

```
parallel -X magick mogrify -format PGM -colorspace gray -depth 8 ::: *.png
```

**HOWEVER**, I would not advise you do that because there are many other things you need to think about:

- if your images contain important meta-data, you need to choose a format that retains it, which is not PGM
- if your images contain floating point pixel data, you should maybe use TIFF format
- if your purpose is to save disk space (which seems silly in this age of nearly free storage), you should consider a compressible format
- if your purpose is to save RAM, there may be no need at all to do any of this as you can just convert your images to single-channel on load, e.g. **OpenCV** `imread(...cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

So, you need to be clearer as to your data and your purposes. Note also that many people claim to want to save *"memory"* and they could mean disk or RAM.

Bear in mind also that PNG can save 8 or 16-bit images, colour or greyscale and with or without a palette (depending on the number of colours) that subsequent applications may or may not be able to handle.