# I have converted 3 channel RGB image into 2 channels grayscale image, How to decrease greyscale channels to 1?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have Converted 3 Channel RGB image into 2 channel grayscale image using :

```py
from PIL import Image
import glob
images = glob.glob('C:/Users/.../*.jpg')
for i in range(len(images)):
    img = Image.open(images[i]).convert('LA')
    img = img.resize((224,224),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save('C:/Users/.../0_{}.png'.format(i))
```

My Goal was to create 1 channel grayscale but after doing code above, i found out that results are 2 channels images ! is there any way that i can decrease this channels to 1 as if i converted them from 3 to 1 at first place ?
Thanks.

Comment: You call `Image.open(images[i]).convert('LA')`. What's the `'LA'` parameter? I don't see it as a valid mode in the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

Comment: I used this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/9099310

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `convert` with `LA` gives it two channels, `L`, which is luminosity, and `A`, which is alpha (transparency). So if you do `Image.open(images[i]).convert('L')` there will only be one channel in the resulting image.

Comment: Best explanation ever.Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If my answer helped you, it's encouraged to mark it as accepted and give it an upvote.

Comment: My reputation is not high , but i did Upvote. Thanks again.