# Convert 3 channel image to 1 channel python

Tags: python, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am using Unet for segmentation in python and my unet's output is a mask with this shape [512,512,1].

After predicted a mask I want to do f1 score between the predicted mask and the real mask of the test image. I need to convert the real mask from [512,512,3] to [512,512,1] and I just can convert to [512,512].

Can anyone help me?
[Image with my outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko5wF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

- - - - - OR

Using matplotlib and [the formula](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)

```
Y' = 0.2989 R + 0.5870 G + 0.1140 B
```

you could do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
gray = rgb2gray(img)
plt.imshow(gray, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python) for more info

Comment: Thanks but your code doesn´t help me. I improve my question to better understand

Answer (score 0):

I discover the answer. I had to remove one axis

predicted.shape
 [512,512,1]

predicted = predicted[:, :,:, 0]

predicted.shape
 [512,512]