# Converting image to grayscale python

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone help with the code to go after for loop to convert to grayscale either by average method or weighted method

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy


myImage = matplotlib.pyplot.imread('flower.png')

height=myImage.shape[0]
width=myImage.shape[1]

for x in range(0, height-1):
    for y in range(0,width-1):

      INSET CODE HERE


imgplot = matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(myImage)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already been a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python) about this - you can either use PIL easily or create it yourself with Numpy and Matplotlib.