# changing colorful dataset to Grayscale using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I loaded a dataset from the AstroNN library. Since i believe the color of images is not a factor for classifying galaxy formations, I want to convert all the dataset to Grayscale to reduce the size of images. How should i do this to the entire dataset?

here's part of my code which loads dataset and splits it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfl
from astroNN.datasets import load_galaxy10
from tensorflow.keras import utils
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import math
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras import layers , models
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import lodgepole.image_tools as lit



# To load images and labels (will download automatically at the first time)
# First time downloading location will be ~/.astroNN/datasets/
images, labels = load_galaxy10()

# To convert the labels to categorical 10 classes
labels = utils.to_categorical(labels, 10)

# To convert to desirable type
labels = labels.astype(np.float32)
images = images.astype(np.float32)


#Split into train and test set

train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(np.arange(labels.shape[0]), test_size=0.1)
train_ds, train_labels, test_ds, test_labels = images[train_idx], labels[train_idx], images[test_idx], labels[test_idx]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by getting the mean over the channel axis for each image with np.mean(array,axis=2).

I've downloaded your data and looked at it again. Since your first dimension is your batch_size, you don't want to average over the 3rd axis. You color channels on the 4th axis so we'll average on it and get the desired form.

[image]

You don't have to make them greyscale in order to train your network but if you especially want it you can go and check the following link:
[How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)

Comment: thanks alot. i added this line of code(train_ds = np.mean(train_ds,axis=2)).  and i noticed my pictures color have chaneged but still not grayscale.is it ok??

Comment: and after i run this (print(train_ds.shape)) the shape is still (19606, 69, 3).

Comment: I've edited the code, hope this answer your questions.

Comment: i really appreciate your time and effort. it helped.