# How to show image in grayscale

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

for some reason this isn't working.

i may be making a silly mistake somewhere.
please help

```
# importing modules
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

#dowload mona lisa image

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/1024px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg',
   "Mona_Lisa.png")
```

#open the file

```
img = Image.open("/content/Mona_Lisa.png")
```

#convert to from rgba to rgb

```
rgb_image = img.convert('RGB')
rgb_image_rgb = np.array(rgb_image)
```

#show image

```
plt.imshow(rgb_image_rgb, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
```

Comment: did you check ImageOps.grayscale()? which also from pillow library

Comment: You've taken a JPEG image and arbitrarily pretended it's a PNG - kind of like sticking a Ferrari badge on your Fiat, it doesn't make it a Ferrari. Then you've saved it in the current directory but opened a completely different file in your top-level `/content` directory. Then you've made it 3-channel RGB for no apparent reason when you really want 1-channel greyscale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried this answer ?

[How can I convert an RGB image into grayscale in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python)

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the image to grayscale using [PIL.Image.convert](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert):

```py
img = Image.open("/content/Mona_Lisa.png").convert("L")
```