# How can i convert images into grayscale?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network, grayscale

I have 1000 of images. Now I like to convert those images into grayscale?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
#df['image_name'] = df['image_name'].apply(str)
df_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(df.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img('/content/drive/MyDrive/Predict DF from Image of Chemical 
    Structure/2D image/'+df['image_name'][i]+'.png',target_size=(100,100,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    df_image.append(img)
X = np.array(df_image)
```

Comment: Are you looking for code or the concept. You can refer to solutions @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [TensorFlow documentation for `tf.keras.utils.load_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img#returns), it accepts the argument `color_mode`, which is

> One of "grayscale", "rgb", "rgba". Default: "rgb". The desired image format.

and it also returns "A PIL `Image` instance.".

The best way to do this is

```py
img = image.load_img(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/Predict DF from Image of Chemical Structure/2D image/'+df['image_name'][i]+'.png',
    target_size=(100,100,3),
    color_mode="grayscale"
)
```

If I'm misinterpreting the documentation, the following should also work (put this after `load_img` but before `img_to_array`):

```py
img = img.convert("L") # if you need alpha preserved, "LA"
```

Since this is a PIL `Image` instance, it has the `.convert` method. `"L"` converts the image to just ***l***ightness values